# jquery reset the css value of an animation?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a created a snippet of code that basically animates an h2 onto an image on hover and then off the right on hover off, so i've initially set the h2 to be left: -200px off the page on load, then on hover to animate to left: 10px inside the .image and then on hover off to animate to left: 500px to zoom off. Now when I hover the image again the h2 is being animated in from the right, how can I reset the h2 to be -200px as soon as the hover off has happened or can you suggest a better way for me to achieve this effect?

My attempt can be found here http://jsfiddle.net/kyllle/GPve7/

Thanks

Comment: Is this what you wanted to achieve? http://jsfiddle.net/geko/GPve7/3/

Comment: @Sleeperson, thanks for the reply. No what I want to do is have the h2 slide onto the image on hover then on hover off the h2 moves across the image to the right not back to the left. when you hover back onto the image then the same animation happens again

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at the [animate function](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) from jquery, it has a callback property, just set the CSS after that:

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GPve7/11/)

Comment: thanks, i had included a callback in the 2nd animate function but was using it wrong

Answer (score 1):

Just reset the position after the second animation is finished using the callback argument in animate() like here http://jsfiddle.net/geko/GPve7/9/